# .Net 4 Web API receiving NULL data in parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am a Web API newbie writing a RESTFul Web Api service in .Net 4. I have configured a controller for a class I am calling `Authentication`. The problem I am having is that when I Post or Put JSON data to the web api service, my handlers in the controller are called, but the parameter objects have NULL data in them. I can successfully Get data, but Post and Put come up with empty parameter objects.

I have tested from a client application and Fiddler, and I get the same result.  Here is what I am sending from Fiddler:

```
Action: PUT
URI: http://127.0.0.1:81/Authentication/xyz/
HTTP Version: HTTP/1.1
Request Headers:
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: 127.0.0.1:81
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 75
Request Body:
{"hashvalue":"kbVFNeBbNHmYQXXlS6d7Ag==","password":"test","username":"dan"}
```

When I set a breakpoint in the Put handler in the Authentication controller:

```
    public void Put(string IDstring, Authentication value)
    {

    }
```

I get the following in the watch window:

```
IDstring                    null    string
value   {bbsRESTResources.Authentication}   bbsRESTResources.Authentication
    hashvalue   null    string
    password    null    string
    username    null    string
```

my Authentication class looks like this:

```
namespace bbsRESTResources
{
    public class Authentication
    {
        public string username;
        public string password;
        public string hashvalue;
    }
}
```

my Route looks like this:

```
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Please don't concern yourself with whether or not this is a good way to handle authentication. This is just a first pass at testing my application from end-to-end. I have looked for examples of other people having this problem and have found none.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that the model binder only works on properties, not fields. As a result, I needed to make properties out of the individual members of the `Authentication` class.  When I changed my definition of the Authentication class to the following, it works:

```
public class Authentication
{
    public string hashvalue {get; set;}
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Also, just as a note of a sticking point that I had regarding another issue that can cause the same problem.  Make sure the content type line is "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem (parameter objects were null), different cause.  I had marked my model as Serializable, and for some reason model binding didn't work when I did that.  Once I removed the attribute, binding worked again.

Comment: This is very strange, I have issue similar to that is described in the question, and removing Serializable attribute helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

And define method as

```
public void Put(Authentication value)
{

}
```

Comment: I cleaned up my route to send {username} and changed method declaration to: public void Put(string username, Authentication value). Now, I get the username correctly, but the value is still an Authentication object with all null values for the members.  The Post handler is coded as you posted (but called Post), and it also returns nulls for the members of the Authentication object.